Send users in a question ban to the Staging Ground when asking a question
This is something that has been raised a few times, both on announcement posts and in the private Team; however, I am posting a formal request to make it so that users that are in a question ban are instead sent to the Staging Ground (SG) when they post a question. I am also proposing that such users may be permitted to post more often (to the SG), if their prior question was promoted and (to use SO's terminology) "survived". Perhaps, if the post was promoted and "survived", they could post again in 1 month's time, as opposed to the usual 6. If it isn't, I'm also not against lowering the rate-limit to 3 months, with it increasing back up to 6, if they can't get posts out of the SG.
To re-touch on why this would be good for the community and the banned users:

Users that are question banned often can end up digging themselves quite a hole. When they can post another new question, it's not uncommon for these to still be received poorly; sometimes this is just because the user doesn't care, others because the on-boarding is/was bad. Sending the user to the SG means that they can't dig a deeper hole; if the question isn't promoted they don't end up with more downvotes and more deleted questions.
Because the user can't dig a deeper hole, this also means that it's easier for them to get out of said ban, because if (when) their posts are promoted, assuming they were well asked, they will achieve upvotes. The bad questions can't get downvotes, as hopefully they never got promoted; this puts the odds in their favour rather than against (as it often feels is the case).
The SG allows for on-boarding and teaching the user how to improve their question, and it's not an area for answering. They are, therefore, much more likely to engage with responses and improve their question; the chances of someone answering in the comments is much lower and the user base engaging with users in the SG is different to those on the main site.

I realise that there's some complexity to the logic here, and it may need a phased approach, but I see this as a net-benefit for the community in the long run.

Yup - instead of just displaying a warning, send them to SG (and explain why).

Such users would be sent to the SG already under the current set up, @RobertLongson . This isn't about new contributors, but existing ones that have ended up in the ban and wouldn't be sent to the SG under the current rules.

The SG is only a recent "thing", @RobertLongson . I'd put money on that 99% of users that are post banned have been never been sent to the SG. I think, perhaps, you are missing the point of the request.

I like this proposal a lot; the current avenue for getting out of a post ban is narrow and bleak, and my impression of the guidance we have in the help center & FAQ for such users is that it doesn't seem to be the most intuitive if you're already struggling with crafting good Q/A's. Staging Ground sounds like it would be perfect for this use case; the more users that can be genuinely rescued from post bans, and become productive contributors, the better. Post bans pale in comparison to tailored guidance offered through SG.

@RobertLongson worth keeping in mind that also not all questions from new users go through SG. So, 1. somebody could have been Q-banned before SG went live, thus they never saw it 2. a user can still post questions that don't go through SG and then get a Q-ban based on that.

@zcoop98 "* the current avenue for getting out of a post ban is narrow and bleak*" moreover, in some cases a user may be trying their best but are weighted down by few foolish questions from, say, seven years ago. Going through SG offers a way out rather than just getting a Q-ban for very old mistakes.

I thought vaguely recalled reading something about users with a question ban being banned from SG as well?

Are you thinking of this question @starball ?

@VLAZ it's worth nothing that SO have confirmed that they do plan for 100% of eligibile users to go to the SG.

@ThomA yet they don't currently. So it's still possible to get Q-banned without ever having a question in SG.

Agreed; it's omitted, but this does run under the assumption that the SG is in "full swing", @VLAZ , as 100% of post banned users would need to be sent.to the SG.

To be honest, I think this would do more damage than good unless we have the reviewers to send 100% of users to the Staging Ground and handle question-banned users as well. Unless this is the case, it would result in a lot of work for question-banned user that could be better spent on improving questions from actual first posters/avoiding question bans.

Time will tell if a bit of an automated wall is needed for those who cannot or will not improve.

@dan1st What makes you so certain that Q-banned users would be less successful through staging ground, or that effort is better spent on new users instead?

@zcoop98 If someone is question-banned, they were likely already told that their questions have certain issues and (assuming that most question banned users have asked more than one question which I don't know) it didn't get any better so I feel like the chances of these users writing good questions (even with effort from others) is rather low. I just think we'd have even more users that just want their question published and don't care about their quality (and these users are kind of annoying to deal with in the Staging Ground - even with the "Decline Re-Evaluation option).

SG is a solution to a problem but not the problem caused by users who disregard feedback to question and end up being question banned. I am less hopeful of users being stuck in SG land because in my experience users who end up being question banned are not into their question being part of the community

I have seen far too many, poorly-onboarded users get banned before they even find out SO isn't a helpdesk to not have great pity.

@user4581301 - I lost my ability to feel pity to individuals who don't educate themself on what our community is about, especially users, who don't plan to be part of our community

@SecurityHound The point of onboarding is to make that education practical to get.  The fact that they would understand that if they read the right page(s) of the several dozen in the help center" is...not a realistic expectation.  Heck, [ask] (y'know...the page that sums up how to do the thing that generally draws people here) isn't even shown when you open the [help].  Sure, it's linked on the word "ask" in the Ask Wizard, but a) that's not really a good way to link that (it doesn't tell you what the link is) and the wizard is saying that it will "guide [them] through the process."

Maybe send them to SG when they get warned about the ban, so they don't get there in the first place.

They could still get banned after that, @gre_gor . Just because a question is promoted from the SG doesn't mean it will get well received, it just has a better chance of being better received. I'm, however, not against users who are in their "last chance" phase going to the SG as well. There's several nuances that likely need working out, hopefully in a proper "this is happening" from SO.

I would also argue that people who are on the edge of getting a question ban should be  treated the same way. If you end up asking several poor questions and then in the staging ground still don't improve... well then you deserve to lose the privilege. People will have a hard time arguing that they were unfairly treated after that.

Hard time SUCESSFULLY arguing, that is. People will find it no harder to argue, and might even be more disgruntled when they swiftly lose.
